# What paint to use for outdoor plastic chairs?

Tags: paint, medium-selection, plastic

I would like to paint my (garden) plastic chairs with nice designs. These are very standard chairs like this one:
[image]
I don't know their exact composition but a google search make me thinking that this is PVC or Polypropylene.

I'm living in central Europe so the paint should resists different types of weather, i.e. *rain*, *sun* and *snow*.

**What are good paints for this purpose?**

During my google search, I noticed that usually spray is recommended for such works. However, I would like to something like in the following example:
[image]
And for such patterns, spray seems very unconvenient (moreover, I'm not really used to work with sprays)...

<sup>Click on the pictures to get redirected to their source on the web</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a plastic chair in my workshop. It is spattered with acrylic paint which is very hard to remove. I suggest you use good quality exterior grade acrylic paints. I have painted concrete ornaments with student grade acrylics and then sprayed them with automobile gel coat. It protects the paint and gives a shiny surface.

Answer (score 3):

I'd also use a specialty undercoat.

Your DIY store or paint store should be able to supply an undercoat with extra grip designed to grip to difficult surfaces. I recently bought some. It's called Grip Lock Primer. It needs 3-4 days to cure completely.

You can also use it for fibreglass, ceramics, laminates. I'm sure you can find similar products in Europe.